# Running into the "cannot find module" with AWS lambda... sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Been working on some lambdas and all of a sudden I started running into this error. The strange thing is that everything was working fine until a certain point in time, at which point all get requests to that endpoint returned an internal server error. I looked in cloud watch to find the "Runtime.ImportModuleError" error type. "Cannont find module 'yadda yadda' \n require stack....."

I have tried several things. I tried using 7zip instead of compress-archive (just made it a different module that couldn't be found). I tried removing aws-sdk from the package.json and this is the part that really makes me feel insane. After removing that, rezipping, and reuploading this made it work. I thought it was solved so I resumed working on the lambda, but when I zipped and uploaded again it was back to the same error. At this point I took a break, looked some stuff up, and came back. The same lambda that was previously not working now worked perfectly fine with no changes from me. Tried zipping and uploading again, back to module cannot be found error. I'm at my wits end here, what the heck could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

From the error you get from the cloudwatch its clear that some of the module that your lambda function needs is not present in the `node_module` directory and removing it from the package.json doesn't affect the lambda function because the lambda doesn't use the package.json to install the dependencies, this has been done manually.

For dependencies Lambda completely relies on the modules that you attached to your zipped( or s3:// bucket) file.

There are few things you can check to analyze

1. Re-align your package.json file with required dependencies and run the `npm install`
2. It could be possible that your lambda function using lambda layers for dependencies and that layers weren't included in the configuration.

Comment: I am running npm install before I zip. The main thing that confuses me is how lambdas will throw the error when I first upload them and then start working later. For instance, last night before logging off for the day I uploaded a new zip. When I pinged the endpoint in Postman I got internal server error, Cloudwatch showed the cannot find module error.

This morning I just logged on and pinged the endpoint, everything works fine.

Comment: would you share the code and triggers you have for the lambda setup, without that information its like shooting arrows in the dark.